# Fields on Knowledge Article Not Displayed On Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, knowledge

I have a Lightning component to display a list of Knowledge Articles. The code runs ok and seems to enter the `<aura:iteration` as the colons are displayed and looking at the debug log the query is returning results however the fields themselves like Title are not displayed when I run this in developer console.

component

```
<aura:component description="ArticleList" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  controller="ArticleListController">

<aura:attribute name="articles" type="SObject[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<aura:iteration var="article" items="{!v.articles}">
    <p>{!article.Id} : {!article.Title} : {!article.ArticleType}</p>
</aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({

doInit: function(component, event){
    var action = component.get("c.getArticles");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    component.set("v.articles", response.getReturnValue());

    });
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

apex controller

```
public with sharing class ArticleListController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<List<SObject>> getArticles() {
    String searchVar = 'Unpredictable';
    List<List<SObject>> articles = [FIND :searchVar RETURNING      KnowledgeArticleVersion
    (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Knowledge__kav','Attachment__kav'))];
    return articles;

}

}
```

Comment: You're returning a List of Lists from your controller but looking at your Lightning attribute, you're expecting only a List. You may want to restructure your return from getArticles to return a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to refactor your code to return a strict list of sObject rather than list< list< sobject>>

```
@AuraEnabled
 public static List<SObject> getArticles() {
    String searchVar = 'Unpredictable';
    list<Sobject> lstresult = new list<Sobject>();
    List<List<SObject>> articles = [FIND :searchVar RETURNING      KnowledgeArticleVersion
           (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Knowledge__kav','Attachment__kav'))];
   lstresult.add(articles[0]);
   lstresult.add(articles[1]);
   return lstresult;
}
```